# Is empty set subset of powersets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$\{ \}$ is subset of each set. 
Then, Let $C=\{a, \{a\}\}$

Now, $C=\{a, \{a\}\}$ is equivalent to 
$C=\{\{\},a, \{a\}\}$ And, 
$\mathcal{P}(C)= \{ \{\} ,\{\{ \}\}, \{a\}, \{\{a\}\}, \dots $

Now, is $C\cap \mathcal{P}(C)$ =$\{\}$ ?

Comment: The set $\{a, \{a\}\}$ and  $\{\{\}, a, \{a\}\}$ are NOT same. The first set has $2$ elements, whereas the second set has $3$ elements.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: { } is subset of each set.So, by default it must be a part of every set?

Comment: Emptyset is subset of **every** set, and thus also of $\mathcal P(A)$, for $A$ whatever. And is also a *memeber* of $\mathcal P(A)$, because it is subset of $A$.

Comment: " $ \{  \} $ is subset of each set.So, by default it must be a part of every set?" - no, **subsets** of a set are a *different type of thing* than **elements** of a set. You're going to have to get that straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a classic case of the subset/member confusion. That $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set does **not** mean that it's a member.

$C$ has the members $a$ and $\{a\}$ and no more. $\{\}$, $\{a\}$, $\{\{a\}\}$ and $\{a,\{a\}\}$ are subsets of $C$. While there is a subset $\{a\}$ that also happens to be a member does not make this true in general - for the other elements/subsets they are all different.